# Pasar como parámetro a una función un objeto que pueda ser de diferentes tipos. C#

Tags: c#, object

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en C# donde tengo declarados algunos tipos de objeto, como Cliente y Factura, declarados en la misma clase. Necesito usar una función que me permita llamar a la función con tipo objeto, donde dentro de la función ya se haga la discriminación de tipo, pero necesito que sea ese único parámetro de tipo objeto que me acepte los tipos de objeto Cliente y Factura.

A la hora de declarar la función y sus parámetros, he intentado ponerlo de tipo Object, pero cuando llamo a la función en el Form1 con un objeto de tipo Cliente da error. Encontré que se podría solucionar con los casting pero no tengo muy claro cómo funciona.

Saludos, y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Podrías explicar porqué tu método necesita recibir objetos de dos tipos tan dispares como `Cliente` y `Factura`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No necesitas una función que distinga entre dos tipos distintos. Necesitas dos funciones:

```
private class Cliente{}
private class Factura{}

static void Funcion(Cliente c)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cliente");
}

static void Funcion(Factura f)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Factura");
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Funcion(new Cliente()); // Llama a la versión Cliente
    Funcion(new Factura()); // Llama a la versión Factura
}
```

Esto se conoce como polimorfismo a nivel de función o [polimorfismo Ad hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism).

Comment: Para mi, sobre carga de metodo es mas facil de entender que polimorfismo ad hoc. +1

Answer (score 2):

Otra solución puede ser el uso de métodos genéricos en clases que heredan de una misma interfaz:

```
public interface ISimilar {}

public class Factura: ISimilar {}
public class Cliente: ISimilar {}

static void Funcion<T>(T similar) where T: ISimilar
{
  Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
}

public static void Main()
{
    Funcion<Factura>(new Factura());
    Funcion<Cliente>(new Cliente());
}
```

Aunque esto puede traer problemas con objetos que no son para nada relacionados, en ese caso es mejor utilizar la respuesta de PaperBirdMaster.

Answer (score 0):

Adicional a los dos soluciones ya expuestas, una técnica mas es utilizar un **tipo de dato débilmente tipado**. Puedes utilizar [dynamic y expandoObject](https://thatcsharpguy.com/post/dynamic-expandoobject/) para este propósito.

Por ejemplo:

```
using System.Dynamic;

namespace EjemploDynamic
{
    class Program
    {
        private class Cliente { }
        private class Factura { }

        private static void EscribeTipoDato(dynamic objeto)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(objeto.cliente + ":" + objeto.cliente.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine(objeto.factura + ":" + objeto.factura.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine(objeto.numero + ":" + objeto.numero.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine(objeto.cadena + ":" + objeto.cadena.GetType());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic objeto = new ExpandoObject();
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
            Factura factura = new Factura();

            objeto.numero = 1;
            objeto.cliente = cliente;
            objeto.factura = factura;
            objeto.cadena = "ejemplo";

            EscribeTipoDato(objeto);
        }
    }
}
```

Yo lo utilizo en ocasiones en que necesito, por ejemplo, una lista cuyos items sean dos variables, y no quiero crear una clase genérica únicamente para estas dos variables.

Comment: Pero para lo que decis, en tu ejemplo de cuando lo necesitas, no te sirve un objeto anonimo?

Comment: @gbianchi si solo fueran para efectos de lectura, si se puede usar. Pero si necesitas manipularlos no, las propiedades de un objeto anónimo son de solo lectura.